# Counting legal pairings on circle with mixed pairing behaviors

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose an even number of red dots and an even number of blue dots are placed arbitrarily onto the circumference of a circle. The placement may be described by the placement vector

$P = (i_1, j_1, i_2, j_2, \ldots, i_k, j_k)$

which reflects $i_1$ red dots, followed by $j_1$ blue dots, followed by $i_2$ red dots... so on and so forth, where $\exists m, n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $\sum i_k = 2m$ and $\sum j_k = 2n$.

The blue dots all need to be paired with blue chords; the red dots all need to be paired with red chords. Blue chords cannot intersect any chords, but red chords are allowed to intersect other red chords.

For instance, here is a legal pairing configuration for $P = (2,2,2,2)$.

[image]

[Legal pairing; $P=(2,2,2,2)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbIB3.png)

How many ways are there to accomplish this for a arbitrary placement vector P? A closed form would be ideal, but failing that, can this quantity be sharply bounded from above?

Comment: Do you have any preliminary knowledge? For example, how many solutions there are if the number of red points is zero, so you are looking for non-intersecting chords?

Comment: Yes; in the situation you describe, pairing 2n points on a circle with non intersecting chords; the number of ways to accomplish this is the n-th Catalan number.

Comment: Then it's also easy to do if there are exactly two red dots.  If the groups of blues are odd, it can't be done, and if they're of sizes $2k$ and $2m$ it's $C_kC_m$